# ANOVA comparison between genders controlling for additional factor

Tags: r, anova, variance

I am interested in finding out exam results differ between gender, controlling for the school the students attended. For now i have done ANOVA comparison of exam results. There are significant differences, according to ANOVA test.

**How can I control for the school?**

There are only three different schools. I am doing the analysis in R. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to post my data. The amount of respondents in each group in not the same.

**Would two way ANOVA with unequal sample sizes be suitable ?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be appropriate.  You can run a two way ANOVA as follows (using the built in mtcars data set as an example).

```
summary(aov(mpg ~ cyl + gear, data = mtcars))
```

which yields ...

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
cyl          1  817.7   817.7   78.29 9.82e-10 ***
gear         1    5.4     5.4    0.52    0.477    
Residuals   29  302.9    10.4                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In addition, if you just wanted to compare two specific groups, you could us a t-test.  Something like this would work.

```
# Create sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
    SchoolA_males = round(runif(10, 50, 100),0), 
    SchoolA_females = round(runif(10, 50, 100),0),
    SchoolB_males = round(runif(10, 50, 100),0), 
    SchoolB_females = round(runif(10, 50, 100),0),
    SchoolC_males = round(runif(10, 50, 100),0), 
    SchoolC_females = round(runif(10, 50, 100),0)
)
# Run a t-test
t.test(df$SchoolA_males, df$SchoolA_females)

# And don't forget some nifty box plots!
boxplot(df)
```

[image: grades by school and gender]

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your scenario, which there's very minimal information on. If you do end up running the ANOVA, make sure you use [type III SS](https://www.r-bloggers.com/anova-%E2%80%93-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/); as these tests [are not reliant on cell size or order of parameters](http://www.dwoll.de/r/ssTypes.php#codeIII). I am not quite sure how to get type III for the individual parameters without manual multiplication by contrast (will add example within a day or 2), but you can use this for the overall model:

```
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum", "contr.poly")) 

### Dummy up data -----
set.seed(123)

df <- mapply(
  function(ns, mns, sds){ rnorm(ns,mns,sds) }, 
  ns = c(19, 20, 19, 23, 20, 19), # n
  mns = c(80, 82, 77, 83, 88, 75), # mean
  sds = c(5, 4, 4, 3, 7, 3) # sd
)
names(df) <- c('Male_A', 'Male_B', 'Male_C', 'Female_A', 'Female_B', 'Female_C')

df <- stack(df)

### Construct orthogonal contrasts -----
con1 <- c(-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1) # Male vs. Female
con2 <- c(2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0) # Male school A vs Male schools B & C
con3 <- c(0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0) # Male school B vs Male school C
con4 <- c(0, 0, 0, 2, -1, -1) # Female school A vs. Female schools B & C
con5 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1) # Female school B vs. Female school C

conts <- cbind(con1, con2, con3, con4, con5)

### Model -----
mod1 <- lm(values ~ ind, data = df,
           contrasts = list(ind = conts))
summary(mod1)

Anova(mod1, type = '3')
```

Once the type III SS is used, the first contrast code will represent the distance between males and females over and above the "effect of school".